# how to loop on the graph only when button is click with bokeh and jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am running Bokeh into Jupyter notebook :

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
```

I have an example of a graph running forever thanks to the callback function

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.driving import cosine
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider

x = np.linspace(0, 4*pi, 80)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure()
r1 = p.line([0, 4*pi], [-1, 1], color="firebrick")
r2 = p.line(x, y, color="navy", line_width=4)

session = push_session(curdoc())

@cosine(w=0.03)
def update(step):
    r2.data_source.data["y"] = y * step
    r2.glyph.line_alpha = 1 - 0.8 * abs(step)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)
session.show(p)
session.loop_until_closed()
```

My problem is I would like to run/update this graph **only when the user wants it** (via a button or a customJS it doesn't matter how if it works!)

I don't find any option to do that. Does someone know if it possible with Bokeh ?
Thank you!

Comment: perhaps this: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/server/line_animate_widget.py

Comment: Yes ! It was exactly what I wanted! Thank you bigreddot.